# How to align a svg button inside an inner-grid?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGZ3F.png)

Hi,
I am making a web application in react js. While making it responsive, I cannot fix the gap that has been created above the svg button's column. Please help me fix it.
I need help to fix the gap above the svg button as shown in the image. Please open the above url to view the image.
Thanx

HTML:

```
<div className="pizza-btn-grid">
                <div className="select-pizza-size">
                  <h4>Please select size</h4>
                  <div>
                    <button>8"</button>
                    <button>13"</button>
                    <button>16"</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="pizza-counting-grid">
                  <h4>How many?</h4>
                  <div className="pizza-counter">
                    <div className="num-of-pizzas">
                      <div className="pizza-counter-wrapper">
                        <div className="column">
                          <button className="btn-pizza-count">1</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="column">
                          <div className="btn-svg">
                            <button>
                              <svg
                                stroke="currentColor"
                                fill="currentColor"
                                stroke-width="0"
                                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                                height="1em"
                                width="1em"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                              >
                                <path d="M256 217.9L383 345c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0 9.4-9.4 9.3-24.6 0-34L273 167c-9.1-9.1-23.7-9.3-33.1-.7L95 310.9c-4.7 4.7-7 10.9-7 17s2.3 12.3 7 17c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l127.1-127z"></path>
                              </svg>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div className="btn-svg">
                            <button>
                              <svg
                                stroke="currentColor"
                                fill="currentColor"
                                stroke-width="0"
                                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                                height="1em"
                                width="1em"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                              >
                                <path d="M256 294.1L383 167c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0s9.3 24.6 0 34L273 345c-9.1 9.1-23.7 9.3-33.1.7L95 201.1c-4.7-4.7-7-10.9-7-17s2.3-12.3 7-17c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l127.1 127z"></path>
                              </svg>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="add-to-cart">
                      <button>add to cart</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


CSS:
 .pizza-btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 90px auto;
    grid-template-rows: 50px;
  }

  .select-pizza-size button {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .pizza-name h1 {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 650;
  }

  .pizza-name h2 {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  .pizza-name p {
    padding: 5px 0 8px 0;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: 500;
    color: gray;
  }

  .pizza-name h4 {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgb(85, 83, 83);
    padding: 0 0 3.5px 0;
  }

  .select-pizza-size {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .pizza-counter {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 95px;
    column-gap: -25px;
    height: 25px;
    /* border: 1px solid; */
  }

  .pizza-counter-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    height: inherit;
    /* gap: 0; */
  }

  .column {
    height: 25px;
  }

  .column button {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .num-of-pizzas {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    width: 45px;
    height: inherit;
    gap: 0;
    /* border: 1px solid; */
  }

  .btn-pizza-count {
    width: 25px;
    height: inherit;
  }

  .pizza-counting-grid button svg {
    font-size: 8px;
  }

  .btn-svg {
    /* display: inline; */
    width: 20px;
    height: 12.5px;
  }

  .btn-svg button {
    /* border: none; */
    width: 20px;
    height: 12.5px;
  }

  button {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb(115, 115, 117);
  }

  button:hover {
    background-color: var(--orange);
    border: none;
  }

  .add-to-cart {
    display: flex;
  }

  .add-to-cart button {
    height: inherit;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
```

Comment: Unless we see the CSS, I don’t think much help can be provided

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.